# Backup and Restore of tempdb in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Can we take a backup of tempdb?

If yes, then How?

If no, then why is there an option in SSMS for restore?

Comment: tempdb is re-created every server start so has no useful data in it. It can't be restored because is always in use by the system processes as well as user processes

Comment: There are [Restrictions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx) for tempdb. backup is one of them !

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't.

```
BACKUP DATABASE tempdb
TO DISK = 'D:\Backups\tempdb.bak'
```

> Msg 3147, Level 16, State 3, Line 63 Backup and restore operations are
>   not allowed on database tempdb. Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 63
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your third question, which is "why is there an option in SSMS for restore?", I have this:

There is no option available from right-clicking "tempdb" to do a restore:

[image]

If you attempt to use the "Restore Database" command by right-clicking the "Databases" node, none of the options allow you to select tempdb from the list of available databases as the target of a restore operation.  You *can* manually type in the name `tempdb` into the "To Database" text box:

[image]

However, doing that will result in this error:

[image]

If you attempt to use the T-SQL `RESTORE DATABASE tempdb ...` command, you get this error:

```
Msg 3147, Level 16, State 3, Line 1  
Backup and restore operations are not allowed on database tempdb.  
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1  
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```